# Facing issue with Datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetime, jquery-plugins

I am using DateTime picker of JQuery. I am having two date fields **StartDate** and **EndDate**.I want to set `minDate` for **StartDate** and `maxDate`  for **EndDate** *dynamically*.

I have tried with the below Code.

```
 $("#StartDate").datetimepicker({
          maxDate: new Date($("#EndDate").val()),
          //value: defaultStartDateTime,
          onSelectDate: function (ct, ab) {      
                          var   startdate = ct.dateFormat('m/d/Y');
                          $('#StartDate').datetimepicker('option', 'value', startdate);
                          $("#EndDate").datetimepicker('option', 'minDate',startdate);
                        },
          step: 15,
          closeOnDateSelect: true,
          format: 'm/d/Y H:i'
      });

 $("#EndDate").datetimepicker({
           minDate: new Date($('#StartDate').val()),
           // value: defaultEndDateTime,
           onSelectDate: function (datetext,dt) {
                          var endDate = datetext.dateFormat('m/d/y');
                          $('#EndDate').datetimepicker('option', 'value', endDate);
                          $('#StartDate').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(endDate));
                        },
           step: 15,
           closeOnDateSelect: true,
           format: 'm/d/Y H:i'
      });
```

**Problem :**

I am facing issue with the above code. I am not able to set the `minDate` and `maxDate` for StartDate and EndDate.It is by default pointing to today's Date as Min Date for EndDate.

**Question :**

- How I can I achieve in setting the MinDate for EndDate and MaxDate
  for StartDate?
- How to override the default behavior and set the date dynamically?

Comment: which datepicker plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the the work around

```
 $("#StartDate").datetimepicker(
                    {
                        maxDate: new Date($("#EndDate").val()),
                        value: defaultStartDateTime,
                        onSelectDate: function (ct) {
                $("#EndDate").datetimepicker({minDate,new Date(ct)});
                        },
                        step: 15,
                        closeOnDateSelect: true,
                        format: 'm/d/Y H:i'
                    });

 $("#EndDate").datetimepicker(
                    {
                        minDate: new Date($('#StartDate').val()),
                        value: defaultEndDateTime,
                        onSelectDate: function (datetext) {
                            $('#StartDate').datetimepicker({maxDate, new Date(datetext)});
                        },
                        step: 15,
                        closeOnDateSelect: true,
                        format: 'm/d/Y H:i'
                    });
```